# Change Contextual ActionBar close icon in Android

Tags: android

I want to make my Contextual Action Bar show a close icon other than the back arrow, but I'm not succeeding.

To do this, I have changed the `actionModeCloseDrawable` property in my `styles.xml` file: **`<item name="actionModeCloseDrawable">@drawable/ic_baseline_close_24</item>`**, but it is not working, as you can see in the image below:

[image]

This is my code at `styles.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.Material3.Dark.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->

        <item name="fontFamily">@font/roboto_regular</item>

        <item name="actionBarTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.Material3.Dark.ActionBar</item>

        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

        <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
        <item name="actionModeStyle">@style/Widget.App.ActionMode</item>
        <item name="actionModeCloseDrawable">@drawable/ic_baseline_close_24</item>

        <item name="colorSurface">@color/design_default_color_surface</item>  

        <item name="materialCalendarStyle">@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar</item>
        <item name="materialCalendarFullscreenTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar.Fullscreen</item>
        <item name="materialCalendarTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar</item>    
    </style>  

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.Material3.Light" />

    <style name="CustomTextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.Material3.BodyMedium">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorBreviario</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Widget.App.ActionMode" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionMode">
        <item name="titleTextStyle">?attr/textAppearanceHeadline6</item>
        <item name="subtitleTextStyle">?attr/textAppearanceSubtitle1</item>
        <item name="background">@color/material_grey_900</item>
        <item name="actionModeCloseDrawable">@drawable/ic_baseline_close_24</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="toolbarStyle">@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Toolbar.PrimarySurface</item>
        <item name="materialCalendarStyle">@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar</item>
        <item name="materialCalendarFullscreenTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar.Fullscreen</item>
        <item name="materialCalendarTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar</item>    
    </style>
</resources>
```

How it's not working?

If I try this:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.item_voz) {
        if (mActionMode == null) {
            //mActionMode = getActivity().startActionMode(mActionModeCallback);
            mActionMode = ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).startSupportActionMode((androidx.appcompat.view.ActionMode.Callback) mActionModeCallback);

        }      
        getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
        return true;
    }
```

I'm having this error:

> java.lang.ClassCastException:
> org.mi.app.ui.fragments.HomiliasFragment$1 cannot be cast to
> androidx.appcompat.view.ActionMode$Callback
> at org.mi.app.ui.fragments.HomiliasFragment.onOptionsItemSelected(HomiliasFragment.java:127)
> at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performOptionsItemSelected(Fragment.java:3154)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchOptionsItemSelected(FragmentManager.java:2937)
> at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performOptionsItemSelected(Fragment.java:3158)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchOptionsItemSelected(FragmentManager.java:2937)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchOptionsItemSelected(FragmentController.java:427)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(FragmentActivity.java:334)
> at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onMenuItemSelected(AppCompatActivity.java:264)
> at androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onMenuItemSelected(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:109)
> at androidx.appcompat.app.ToolbarActionBar$2.onMenuItemClick(ToolbarActionBar.java:66)
> at androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar$1.onMenuItemClick(Toolbar.java:221)
> at androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionMenuView$MenuBuilderCallback.onMenuItemSelected(ActionMenuView.java:781)
> at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:834)
> at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:158)

This is my callback:

```
private final ActionMode.Callback mActionModeCallback = new ActionMode.Callback() {

    @Override
    public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {

      // ...
    }
// ...
}
```

Comment: How exactly are you starting the action mode?

Comment: @MikeM. The action mode is for audio control, and I'm starting it from a menu selection on the toolbar: `public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) { if (item.getItemId() == R.id.item_voz) { if (mActionMode == null) { mActionMode = getActivity().startActionMode(mActionModeCallback); } // ... }`

Comment: The attributes that you're setting in your theme are for the support/androidx action mode, but you're using the platform action mode when calling `startActionMode()`. If you do mean to be using the library version, you want to use `startSupportActionMode()` instead, for which you'll have to cast `getActivity()` to `AppCompatActivity` first. If you don't mean to be using that, then you'll need to set the platform attributes instead, which basically means just adding the `android:` prefix to them, though that might cause errors/warnings depending on what your `minSdkVersion` is.

Comment: @MikeM. I have tried what you suggest, but it forces me to create the Callback of type `androidx.appcompat.view.ActionMode.Callback` and when executing the code I have a ClassCastException.

Comment: @MikeM. This is my callback: `private final ActionMode.Callback mActionModeCallback = new ActionMode.Callback() {` if I try your recommendation, my callback must be changed to type `androidx.appcompat.view.ActionMode.Callback` and then I have ClassCastException when I try to open the Fragment.

Comment: @MikeM. I will edit my question, adding the changes and the stacktrace.

Comment: @MikeM. I can't do it, Android Studio says me that the required type is `androidx.appcompat.view.ActionMode.Callback`

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't seen your `Callback` declaration in that edit. Yeah, you need to change the `import` statement.

Comment: @MikeM. I changed to this `import androidx.appcompat.view.ActionMode;` now the code is working, but the icon is not changing. I don't understand what's happening.

Comment: Well, it does work: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ycJoa.png. I just used `ic_launcher_foreground` there. My first thought would be that whichever `Activity` this is in doesn't have your theme with the `<item name="actionModeCloseDrawable">` set on it.

Comment: Sorry @MikeM. i don't understand your comment. I'm trying that from one Fragment. What do I need to change to make it work for me?

Comment: Right, but the parent `Activity` will be where the theme for all of this comes from. Whichever `Activity` that is, make sure that its `<activity>` element in your manifest has `android:theme="@style/AppTheme"`.

Comment: Yes @MikeM.  i defined thah in Manifest: `android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"` for the activity (MainActivity) and for the entire `application`.

Comment: I don't see that specific theme defined in the block you've posted here. Is that in another file?

Comment: Is not that: `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.Material3.Dark.NoActionBar">` @MikeM. ?

Comment: No, `AppTheme.NoActionBar` is not `AppTheme`. Where does it take you if you middle-click (or ctrl+B) on `AppTheme.NoActionBar`?

Comment: This goes to file at `v21/styles.xml` at this line: `<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">` @MikeM.

Comment: OK, well, I'm not sure why you have that separate, for only 21+, but for right now, that's where you need to put the `<item name="actionModeCloseDrawable">@drawable/ic_baseline_close_24</item>` line.

Comment: Yes, yes. I don't know why, but the app is taking the file at `v21` folder. I put `<item name="actionModeCloseDrawable">@drawable/ic_baseline_close_24</item>` at this file and now it's working fine. I appreciate that you put it as an answer to give it as valid. I did not know the trick of (ctrl+B). Thanks a lot.

Comment: No problem. Yeah, I can't think of any technical reason why you'd need a `NoActionBar` theme for only Lollipop and above, but theming and styling is a _very_ complicated topic, so I don't want to suggest anything that might break your existing setup. Anyhoo, I don't post answers here any more, but please feel free to put one up yourself, if you'd like. Thank you, though. I appreciate the offer. Glad you got it working. Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

How about using a Toolbar? `androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar` has this method:
`public void setNavigationIcon(@DrawableRes int resId)`

Maybe `activity.actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.id.back)`

Comment: I have a toolbar, which shows the back arrow and I want it to be so, what I want to change is the contextual action bar, which appears when I click an option in the toolbar menu.